# Lights and outlets keep tripping

Tags: electrical

The lights and outlets in out bathroom and livingroom keep tripping?? I did some research and everyone was saying it was the GFCI outlet, so there is only one on that circuit so I replaced it and we thought we fixed it. But the next morning it tripped again!! What else could it be??

Comment: What is tripping the circuit breaker or the GFCI? The lights and outlets in the bath on 1 circuit points to an older home (new has required the bathrooms outlets to be separate circuits) I would try moving where something is plugged in if tripping the breaker you may have the circuit overloaded. If it’s the GFCI there may be an actual ground fault. More info is needed to help.

Comment: It’s just tripping the lights and outlets in that area. Not the breaker. This house was purchased in 2001 it’s a double wide.

Comment: Lights don’t require GFCI protection. It could be a fixture, but we are guessing here, anything plugged in could be run from an extension cord to see if that or those devices are the source. Troubleshooting intermittent problems can be tough. We need to remove what we can from the circuit. Are any of the lights fluorescent? That age is when the electronic ballast were first required, they pushed the date out several times but a faulting electronic ballast would not surprise me.

Comment: Tripping means disconnected from power source? Where the disconnect is?

Comment: Is the circuit breaker actually tripping, or is power to those lights and outlets going out without the breaker for the circuit actually tripping?